# Visual Studio 2017, How to make #include <pthread.h> work?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

I feel like I've been searching for hours today on how to make `#include <pthread.h>` work in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 and haven't come across an answer that has worked. Can someone please instruct me how to get this to work?

The error I receive is: cannot open source file "pthread.h"

Comment: libpthread is typically for *nix. Did you find a Windows version?

Comment: pthread is for Linux POSIX threads and is not bundled with Visual Studio. If you are looking to create threads on windows, look for https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx or use OpenMP

Comment: If you want to sort of avoid this problem, you should be able to use a Linux VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows doesn't natively support pthreads.

There is [an implementation of pthreads for Windows](https://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) you could use. If you're just trying to get some code running on Windows ASAP it may be your best bet.

If you can modify the code, you might want to take a look at what pthread functions you are actually using; if all you need is a mutex a few #ifdefs around pthreads/winapi may be a better way to go.

There are also some projects which implement compatibility layers that aren't as expressive as the full pthreads API, but are more than enough for most projects. [TinyCThread](https://tinycthread.github.io/) is one option (which I maintain, so take the recommendation with a grain of salt) which implements the C11 threads API.

Other options include:

- [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html)
- [libuv](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/guide/threads.html)

[OpenMP](http://www.openmp.org/) could also be a good choice. It is really easy to use, but operates at a higher level and so it may require a more substantial rewrite.

Comment: Maybe I'm just dumb, but I can't seem to be able to download anything from ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/

I can click on everything, but not able to download the zips.

Comment: ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release.zip works for me.

Answer (score 34):

In Visual Studio 2017

1. Project -> Manage Nuget Packages
2. In browse Tab search for 'pthread'
3. Select Install[Search Results in Nuget packages]

[image]

Comment: this is fastest way

Comment: I get an error "1>c:\users\timo\source\repos\consoleapplication1\packages\pthreads.2.9.1.4\build\native\include\pthread.h(320): error C2011: 'timespec': 'struct' type redefinition
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\time.h(39): note: see declaration of 'timespec'"

Comment: @TraceKira I got the same error. There seems to be a bug in pthread.h. If you make a comment out of that specification there, everything is fine again.

Comment: @TraceKira in pthread.h file, remove the lines between 318-324. It'll solve the redefinition problem

Answer (score 10):

For Visual Studio 2017, I've installed through NuGet Packages.

Try below steps,

1. Go to Project > 'Manage NuGet Packages'
2. Browse > search for 'pthread' > install

Answer (score 6):

If you have *vcpkg* installed, then you can just do:

```
vcpkg.exe install pthread
```

That will download some code from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w, compile it and install it in your system. If *vcpkg* is setup correctly on your machine, Visual Studio should use these files automatically.