# Cmake doesn't find boost, pkg config of flaan and pthreads to run a PCL example

Tags: boost, cmake, point-cloud-library, pkg-config

I would like to run an example from the librairy PCL. I need to use cmake in order to link all the different librairy. I installed the correct one from the official website directly,but it turns out that cmake doesn't find some pthread.h, pkg executable and boost. This is the message that I received with the visual c++ 15 compiler :

```
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Found eigen: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/3rdParty/Eigen/include  
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - not found
Found Threads: TRUE  
Could NOT find Boost
```

Do I need to download pkg config ? I thought it was already inside PCL. I tried to add a pthread.h from internet as he can already recognize thread.h but it didn't work out..

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @kalehmann: Please, do not format logs as *blockquote*. This formatting loses original newlines, and log becomes hard to understand. Format logs as a **code** instead.

Comment: You show the log where CMake describes what exists on your system (and what CMake has been able to find), and what does not exist or cannot be found. By itself, "not found" is **not a problem**. E.g., it is known that Visual Studio [lacks for pthread.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894212/visual-studio-2017-how-to-make-include-pthread-h-work). If you hit an **error** during the futher processing, show that error.

Comment: @kalehmann I'm sorry it was my first post on Stack over Flow, I'll keep that in mind